# Using Node.js + Express without template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have tried looking through all of the questions resolved by StackOverflow regarding people receiving this error:

`Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.`

I feel like I have scoured every post on SO and none of the answers have corrected my code. There must be something else going on.

My issue that I am having is that I already created many html files before making a decision to use Node.js + Express for my back-end...so rather than worry about converting them all to a templating engine like pug or EJS, I just want to serve them from a static public folder in my directory.

From what I have researched, you do *not* need a templating engine to use Node.js + Express. But you *do* need to set up a static public folder to serve your files.

I have included the `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` in my app.js file. I have added a 'public' folder and put all of my static files inside of it, and in my routes file (my index.js file) I have written the following route:

`router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('./public/index.html');
});`

I have tried changing it to the following:

1. `res.sendFile('index');`
2. `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')`
3. `res.sendFile('../public/index.html');`

I have also tried changing my static middleware syntax to just `app.use(express.static('public'));` and that didn't seem to change anything either.

All of these render the `No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.` error I provided above. I hate that I need to ask this questions when there are so many of the same questions on StackOverflow, but I am currently completely stumped at to what to do. Without further adieu, here is my code:

This is my file directory structure.

[image]

Here is my index.js file handling all my routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {

});

module.exports = router;
```

Here's my app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
const errorHandlers = require('./handlers/errorHandlers');


const app = express();

app.use('/', routes);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// If that above routes didnt work, we 404 them and forward to error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.notFound);

// One of our error handlers will see if these errors are just validation errors
app.use(errorHandlers.flashValidationErrors);

// Otherwise this was a really bad error we didn't expect! Shoot eh
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  /* Development Error Handler - Prints stack trace */
  app.use(errorHandlers.developmentErrors);
}

// production error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.productionErrors);

module.exports = app;
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "********",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./start.js"
  },
  "author": "****** ********",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongod": "^2.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.1",
    "normalize.css": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here's my start.js file that runs when I run `npm start`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// import environmental variables from our variables.env file
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; 
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`${err.message}`);
});


const app = require('./app');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7777);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible one of your error handlers calls `res.render`?

Comment: I doubt this is the problem but...try `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/index.html'))`. Also, console log in the `router.get('/')` just to see if you get a response.

Comment: @ReyHaynes. This worked! I had to `require` path on the index.js file for it to work, but it worked!. What is the difference between what I had and why would it only accept that syntax...?

Comment: @Josh...Good question! There is actually res.render on some of the errorHandlers in my file. I would imagine that would cause me to run into issues when I actually do have errors. So I will correct them and update them. But it didn't seem as though that was what was breaking my code. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: Glad it worked. I'll pass this as the answer below! To answer the question though, when you have to traverse backward a folder, you need to add a starting forward slash followed by pointing backwards (ie. `/..`).

Comment: First of all change your question because it is not about "node.js without templating engine". This can make more developers confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing this as the answer

Try `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/index.html'))`

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting from scratch, you can run:

```sh
npm install -g express-generator # to install express-generator globally
express projectName --no-view --git # '--git' is optional and generates a '.gitignore' file
```